# Poisson point process convergence

Tags: probability, statistics, stochastic-processes

Let Π be a Poisson point process on [0,∞) with intensity measure $\mu$. Assume $μ([0,t])<∞$ for all $t<∞$ and $μ([0,∞))=∞$. Also assume $μ({x})=0$ for all x. Prove $$\lim_{t→∞}\frac{Π([0,t])}{μ([0,t])}=1 \space \space a.s.$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please tell us what are your thougts on the problem, what have you tried, if you have some idea, etc.

Comment: I tried to apply the mapping theorem, but don't know what could I do with the mapping theorem.